# Getting inputs from USB TV remote

Tags: python, linux, usb, remote-control

I'm running a Linux Debian port on a Raspberry Pi named Debian, and it has Python 3 and 4 installed, I believe. I have an USB remote that looks like a TV remote that I'm trying to receive input from for a program, preferably in python, but have no idea how to get an input from a pressed button on a USB device to relay to instructions.

I need a way to index any USB input presses, so I can map them to inputs to be sent over I2C. It doesn't have to be Python, but I already have other instructions in it and would like to know how to import those controls.

Edit: The controller is an ATI RF remote where the sensor plugs into USB.
http://www.emtcompany.com/ati-100712001-remote-control/101317958.html?gclid=CjwKEAiAhIejBRCKm_fTxIWyyXcSJABXY0XYp_oZmm7_2YdlKFysTH7jS-BXk0ngqoS68crxrrjKAhoCQw_w_wcB

Comment: a link with a remote info would be helpful

Comment: Updated now, thanks. I've gotten suspended a while ago for giving "too much" info (not asking proper questions).